# PHP 000webhost Redirect To File URL

Tags: php, file, url, redirect

How can I direct to another HTML after the PHP process has been done?
Part of PHP process:

```
case "Radeon 3650":
    header("/GPUs/HD3650/8305835/specs.html");
break;
```

I want to redirect the user after the process of case has been done to that html I have in double-quotes. The server I use is 000webhost and it doesn't work.
This PHP is located at public_html, GPUs folder is in that folder and so it goes.
Help? :(

Comment: You forgot the word "Location:". http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and use a full http call as per what the manual suggests.

Comment: You are missing "location". http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I just tried right now with header('Location: /GPUs/HD3650/8305835/specs.html'); and nothing happens. It redirects me to http://error404.000webhost.com/?

Comment: That folder/file doesn't exist then. Make sure your folder/file are the same letter case. `GPUs` and `GPUS` or `gpus` are not the same. Nor is `HD3650` and `hd3650` so check your folder names/case. Those are two different animals altogether ;-) Windows and Linux handle file case differently and you're on a Linux server which is case-sensitive.

Comment: Crap I didn't remember the case-sensitive on the HTML extension xD Thanks a lot Fred! :D

Comment: You're welcome. If you want the question closed and my posting an answer, let me know.

Comment: Yep do that please ^_^

Comment: It has been done, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you forgot the word "Location:" and use a full http call as per what the manual suggests.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also taken from the comments you've given us:

> *I just tried right now with header('Location: /GPUs/HD3650/8305835/specs.html'); and nothing happens. It redirects me to error404.000webhost.com?*

That folder/file doesn't exist or the server cannot find the actual folder/file name(s).

Make sure your folder/file are the same letter case. `GPUs` and `GPUS` or `gpus` are not the same.

Nor is `HD3650` and `hd3650` so check your folder names/files/extensions lettercase.

- *Those are two different animals altogether.*

Windows and Linux handle naming conventions differently and you're on a Linux server which is case-sensitive.